# Very strange behavior when using local storage with github sites

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm making a simple clicker type game in HTML and javascript. I'm using local storage to save the varibles `money` and  `taxCollecters`. I am geting very strange behavior when I try and use the save and load buttons in the github site. I'm really not sure how to explain it, but here's the links:
Code : https://github.com/thebearslicer/testIdle
Site : https://thebearslicer.github.io/testIdle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `money` variable is a Number type until you retrieve it from `localStorage`. It is then a string. So parse the strings back integers:

```
loadBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    money = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('money'));
    taxCollecters = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('taxMen'));
});
```